# How to give a score to each dataframe value based on scorecard in another database?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to create a scorecard for the `values` relative to the `scorecard` (both below).

```
values <- data.frame(A= c(-200,-150,-100,0,100),
                     B= c(100,0,-101,-201,-300),
                     C= c(-400,400,500,-500,250),
                     D= c(NA,NA,-1000,-1000,-1000),
                     E= c(1000,1000,1,-1000,-2000))

scorecard <- data.frame(Names = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                        "Score5" = c(-100,-200,-300,-400,-500))

values
     A    B    C     D     E
1 -200  100 -400 -1000  1000
2 -150    0  400 -1000  1000
3 -100 -101  500 -1000     1
4    0 -201 -500 -1000 -1000
5  100 -300  250 -1000 -2000
```

If A's value < -100 (i.e. `scorecard[1,2]`), the scorecard dataframe should say 5, otherwise it should say 0. And I'd like to do this for all of A, B, C, D and E in one dataframe. The desired output is:

```
#  A B C  D E
#1 5 0 5 NA 0
#2 5 0 0 NA 0
#3 0 0 0  5 0
#4 0 5 5  5 5
#5 0 5 0  5 5
```

I've tried the following - which required the packaged xts: `install.packages("xts")` but I didn't quite get there.

```
pointsfunction <- function(value)  {
  points <- c()
  for(i in names) {
    index = which(colnames(value)==i)
    data_start <- which(!is.na(value))[1]
    points[1:(data_start -1)] <- NA
    for(a in (data_start):(length(value))) {
      if(value[a] < scorecard[index, 2]) {
        points[a] <- -5
      } else {
        points[a] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
  points <- reclass(points, value)
  return(points)
}

scorecardpoints <- as.data.frame(lapply(values, pointsfunction))
```

I got the following error:

> Error in if (value[a] < scorecard[index, 2]) { :    argument is of
> length zero Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about the desired output? Showing the output for your sample input would help a lot. *"f A's value < -100 (i.e. scorecard[1,2]), the scorecard dataframe should say 5, otherwise it should say 0*". Is it always 5 or 0? Or is it the number of `values` that are below the above the scorecard threshold? Should the result have the same "shape" (dimensions) as `scorecard`, or `values`, or something else?

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. I've edited it.
Do you perhaps have an idea for how to solve it with lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

values %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = 'Names') %>%
  left_join(scorecard, by = 'Names') %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value < Score5, 5, 0)) %>%
  select(-Score5) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Names, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Or perhaps a simpler base R option :

```
mat <- sweep(values, 2, scorecard$Score5[match(names(values), scorecard$Names)], `<`)
values[mat] <- 5
values[!mat] <- 0
values

#  A B C  D E
#1 5 0 5 NA 0
#2 5 0 0 NA 0
#3 0 0 0  5 0
#4 0 5 5  5 5
#5 0 5 0  5 5
```

Comment: You can do `mat <- sweep(...) * 5` to simplify the numeric conversion.

Comment: I have expanded the question. Are you able to help?

Comment: Don't expand the question, ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ronak's answer, but here's an apply-family based solution:

```
sapply(names(values), function(x) values[[x]] < scorecard$Score5[scorecard$Names == x]) * 5
#      A B C  D E
# [1,] 5 0 5 NA 0
# [2,] 5 0 0 NA 0
# [3,] 0 0 0  5 0
# [4,] 0 5 5  5 5
# [5,] 0 5 0  5 5
```

Comment: I have expanded the question. Are you able to help?

Comment: You asked a question, got two working answers, and then changed the question so the answers don't work anymore? That's not great. If your original question didn't match the scope of your real problem, accept one of the working answers you got and ask a new question. Don't edit your question and "move the goalposts".

Comment: Especially since those are *drastic* changes to the question. This went from a simple comparison between 2 data frames to comparing 1 data frame to 3 other data frames with several conditionals based on the results.